# lowest numbered "hole" in the sequence

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Given a set of documents in couchbase where each document has an integer value which is initially assigned sequentially, but is then later released out of order, find the lowest numbered "hole" in the sequence

For example, for documents with the following values:

```
1
3
4
6
```

the query should return 0
with these values:

```
0
1
3
4
6
```

the query should return 2
with these values:

```
0
1
2
```

the query should return 3

Answer (score 1):

Create Array of the sequence number in ascending order.

```
SELECT RAW  d.id FROM default AS d WHERE  d.id >= 0  ORDER BY d.id ASC
```

You can use  above query which returns array. Then Append -1 at the end using ARRAY_APPEND() so that we can handle if there is no holes.
Return position of array when pos is not matched with value at position using FIRST collection expression.

Final query:

```
SELECT FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN av WHEN pos != av[pos] END AS hole
LET av = ARRAY_APPEND((SELECT RAW  d.id FROM default AS d WHERE  d.id >= 0  ORDER BY d.id ASC ), -1);

SELECT FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN av WHEN pos != av[pos] END AS hole  LET av = ARRAY_APPEND([1,3,4,6], -1);
SELECT FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN av WHEN pos != av[pos] END AS hole  LET av = ARRAY_APPEND([0,1,3,4,6], -1);
SELECT FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN av WHEN pos != av[pos] END AS hole  LET av = ARRAY_APPEND([0,1,2], -1);
```

If result set is large you can do in batches using application and N1QL to consume less resources and making it faster, some thing like below (Use Index order avoid sort)

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(id);
startpos = 0
endpos = 1000
pos=startpos

WHILE
do
    id = SELECT FIRST pos FOR pos:v IN av WHEN pos != av[pos] END AS hole
         LET av = ARRAY_APPEND((SELECT RAW d.id
                       FROM default AS d USE INDEX (ix1)
                       WHERE d.id BETWEEN $startpos AND $endpos
                       ORDER BY d.id ASC), -1);
    if id <= $endpos
         pos = startpos+id
         break
    else
        startpos = endpos+1
        endpos = endpos+1000
    fi
done

pos will have final hole
```

In the next release of couchbase you can use window functions

```
   CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(id);
    SELECT RAW d.rn-1 AS pos
    FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn, t.id as id  
                     from  default  AS t  USE INDEX (ix1)
                     WHERE  t.id >= 0  
                     ) AS d 
      WHERE (d.rn-1) != d.id 
       LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Perfect .. Thank you